# JPA/Hibernate - INNER JOIN on a concatenated column names

Tags: hibernate, jpa

After multiple Googling, I can't find a working solution to map INNER join that is described as follows in SQL:

```
select i.label, i.cat_label from category cat
inner join items it on (it.context_code||'.'||it.label_code)=cat.cat_label
```

How to define OneToMany in Category entity ? Ho to write a query criteria ?
I tried as follows, no success:

```
Category.java

 @OneToMany
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "CONTEXT_CODE || . || LABEL_CODE"))
    private List <Items> items;


Item.java

 @Formula(value = "CONTEXT_CODE || . || LABEL_CODE")
    private String contextCodeLabelCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `on` clause using `JPQL`. It is allowed in `HQL` for Hibernate 5.1.

If you need to use `JPQL`, you can try to use `cross join` (cartesian product)

```
select it from category cat, items it where ...
```